Excel drop-down list items start from middle of column of Table to end by using spill operator "#"
I have a table for example 8 rows and two drop down list, I want first drop down list has items from 1 --> 4
and the two drop down list has items from 5 --> end
The problem is in the drop down list two cos I used spill operator "#" in source and not work




How about using OFFSET instead?
=OFFSET(A6,0,0,COUNTA(A:A)-5,1)


If you have Microsoft 365, you could try this:

Name the range used for validation (for convenience); here it is named _valid_a. Guide to named ranges
Then for validation DROP(_valid_a,4)



INDEX you may want to try this if you're using older versions
We could use INDEX to specify the range, though not directly (cannot use tables or reference operators), but indirectly:

Define a named range, in this example as _valid_a_ref with =INDEX(_valid_a,5):INDEX(_valid_a,ROWS(_valid_a))

Use this name for validation.



